# Just Read My Lips

Tags: language

> Do you know the game I play? I think that it's quite fun.
>
> Find the rules that bind it, and you just might find the one.
>
> This puzzle's for lovers once kissing - and a missing thing used for things missing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like a stretch, but my guess is

> the letter X.

Do you know the game I play? I think that it's quite fun.

> It could be Tic-Tac-Toe/naughts and crosses (credits to jsm who validated my idea)

Find the rules that bind it, and you just might find the one.

> In this puzzle, the only missing letter is the "X".

This puzzle's for lovers once kissing - and a missing thing used for things missing.

> Lovers once kissing = "ex", which sounds like "X", and x as the variable to be uncovered in maths expressions.

Title:

> It refers to "xoxo" placed at the end of letters or text messages, which means "hugs and kisses". "Read my lips" means "read the x as a kiss". *(credits to tyobrien)*

Comment: "The game I play" would be (abhtugf naq pebffrf)

Comment: @jsm yeah, I tought about it as well, but it looked too much of a stretch... let's add it and let's see :)

Comment: Correct answer. The reasoning is close but not quite there. What did I mean with the title and the game?

Comment: @kedarguru uhm, ok, I'll rack my brains...

Comment: ...by the way, if somebody has a guess for the title or the game, please help me :D

Comment: A certain microsoft console? Or maybe just (k znexf gur fcbg)?

Comment: I’ll give you a hint. You know what it is, but you don’t know the word for it.

Comment: You know the meaning of the characters xoxo...?

Comment: @LinuxBlanket The answer I was looking for might not be common knowledge. A “lipogram” is a form of writing which avoids certain letters, mainly just for fun. The title and the first two lines describe the concept. “Read my lips” is a play on words, “lip-“ is to leave out, so the title suggests that you “read what I have left out”.

Comment: @kedarguru ah sure, a lipogram! I know it, mainly from Queneau's work :) now I feel quite dumb for not thinking about it, it was self-evident

Comment: @LinuxBlanket By solving the riddle you’ve demonstrated an understanding of the concept, even if you didn’t remember the technical term for it, so I give you the win

Comment: @kedarguru thanks, it was a pleasant riddle to read and solve:)

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but I noticed a pattern:

> While prononcing the lines, the lips touch exactly twice every line:
>  Just Read **M**y Li**p**s
>  Do you know the ga**m**e I **p**lay? I think that it's quite fun.
>  Find the rules that **b**ind it, and you just **m**ight find the one.
>  This **p**uzzle's for lovers once kissing - and a **m**issing thing used for things missing.

Comment: There is a last "missing", not counted

Comment: Indeed, **missed** it